# finite Galois extension

Tags: extension-field, galois-extensions

Let $E$ be a finite extension of $F$ and assume that $E/F$ is separable. Since $E/F$ is separable, there is a finite Galois extension $E'$ over $F$, containing $E$: $F \subseteq E \subseteq E'$. Show that

> $E' \cap \bar{F} = F$

$x \in F \implies x \in E'$ (because $F \subseteq E'$) $\land \ x\in \bar{F}$ (because $F \subseteq \bar{F}$) $\implies  x \in E' \cap \bar{F}$

I would like to ask for a tip to show other direction.

Comment: What was $\bar F$ ?

Comment: it's closure of $F$.

Comment: Unless $\;E\;$ and thus $\;E'\;$ are trivial extensions of $\;F\;$ , I don't think that's possible at all...

Comment: Sorry, but I don’t spot what kind of closure you’re referring to. Algebraic closure? Relative algebraic closure (in some bigger field)? Topological closure?

Comment: It's algebraic closure.

Comment: It is common notation to denote by $\;\overline F\;$ the (unique up to isomorphism) algebraic closure of a field $\;F\;$ .

Comment: Then of course, since $E'$ is algebraic over $F$, you have $E'\subset\bar F$

Comment: @Lubin Exactly...and because of that your questions to the OP are in place. This seems to be a rather trivial problem...or else something's missing.

Comment: If $E$ and $F$ are finite, then the extension $E/F$ is automatically separable. So I judged that your use of the tag [tag:finite-fields] was a mistake. Recall, a *field* $F$  is *finite*, if and only it has finitely many elements. An *extension* $E/F$ is *finite* if and only if $E$ is a finite-dimensional vector space over $F$. In the latter case [tag:finite-fields] is not appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see: $\;E=\Bbb Q(\sqrt[4]2)\;$ is a finite extension of $\;F=\Bbb Q\;$, and of course $\;E/F\;$ is separable. $\;E'=\Bbb Q(\sqrt[4]2\,,\,i)\;$ certainly contains $\;E\;$ and $\;E'/F\;$ is Galois .

But do you think $\;E'\cap \overline F=\Bbb Q(\sqrt[4]2,\,i)\cap\overline{\Bbb Q}=F=\Bbb Q\;$ ? In fact, it must be $\;E'\cap\overline F=E'\;$ in any case with the given data, since $\;E'\;$ *algebraic* over $\;F\;$ ...!